# Dataweave - Loop in-depth mapping XML

Tags: xml, loops, mule, dataweave, depth

I have a `XML` `payload` that contains the following example:

```
<Example>
    <Brand>
        <Id>987S</Id>
        <logo>circle</logo>
        <Item>
            <Name>cologne1</Name>
            <Item>
                <Name>Bosque</Name>
            </Item>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Name>t-Shirt</Name>
        </Item>
    </Brand>
    <Brand>
        <Id>877823C</Id>
        <logo>circle</logo>
        <Item>
            <Name>t-Shirt2</Name>
            <Item>
                <Name>t-Shirt black</Name>
                <Item>
                    <Name>t-Shirt black with logo</Name>
                </Item>
            </Item>
        </Item>
    </Brand>
</Example>
```

The `XML` is divided into:

- Example as **root node**

  - Brand Objects

    - **Item Objects: Those Items can also contains more Items**

I get this structure randomly until **3 levels in-depth per Item**.

The output expected is all Items in the same level into a parent node:

```
<Supermarket>
    <Item>
        <BarValue>cologne1</BarValue>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <BarValue>Bosque</BarValue>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <BarValue>t-Shirt</BarValue>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <BarValue>t-Shirt2</BarValue>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <BarValue>t-Shirt black</BarValue>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <BarValue>t-Shirt black with logo</BarValue>
    </Item>
</Supermarket>
```

Is there a way to loop the XML file dynamically with Dataweave?

Comment: What would you want to do with the items?

Comment: @Shoki map and transform each item to another kind of object and store in a file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some ways to do this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
{
    Supermarket: {(
        payload..*Item map {
            Item: {
                BarValue: $.Name
            }
        }
    )}
}
```

The descendants selector `payload..Item` gets all the Items in any level. Then for each `Item` we generate an object with `{Item: {BarValue: $.Name}}` and get an `Array` of item objects.

The problem is that the XML model in DataWeave represents element tags and values with `Objects` and `Strings`, there is no concept of `Array` (which was our result of items).

So we use the `Dynamic Object` feature `{(expr)}` where `expr` returns  an `Array` of key value pairs that are expanded into key-value pairs of the object.

Alternative:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
{
    Supermarket: {
        Item: {
            BarValue: payload..*Item.Name
        }
    }
}
```

This last one works because in XML when the writer tries to write an `Array`, it repeats the `Key` (Item) that contains said `Array` (payload..Item.Name)

Comment: Thanks @Shoki. As you said, only returns one object, not an Array, is any way to solve this?

Comment: oh, right, I didn't take into account that an item could have multiple child items in the same level. I'll edit the answer with the MultiValue descendants selector (..*), which is used to match not only the first child.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to collect all the Item elements you can use the [descendant selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-selectors).

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload..Item
```

If this is not what you want please provide an expected output and we can help more